# issue in process builder in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, process-builder

I have two relation A and B, A is parent of B.On update record B I want to update one field in A. I am using the process builder but getting the following error,

> Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow,The record couldn't be saved
>         because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute
>         the flow with version ID xxxxxxxx0000ChAc. Contact your administrator
>         for help. Click here to return to the previous page.

Comment: Please update your question with more info, screenshots, etc. This is just a generic error message Salesforce provides, no way someone can help you out with such a limited amount of information. Help us to help you.

Comment: can you tell me this error reason

Comment: Especially when working with flow and the process builder, error messages are very generic and cannot really help you. It might that you receive an email when this error occurs which contains additional information, but other than that, like @RobinDeBondt told you, no one will answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on the message received: "Contact your administrator for help". System admin will receive an email from *FlowApplication* with a subject of "Unhandled process fault from *YourOrgName* ..." with more information on what went wrong during the process. This was mention by @westforce also.

Answer (score 1):

I met a similar issue before when triggered a process to create a new record, and the root cause was because  forgot to initiate value to a required field of that record. You can trace your error by viewing log file (Debug log in Salesforce UI or launch Developer Console before running that process)